# Assembly: Is it possible to move (mov) value of variable to memory address?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

According to https://www.ethicalhacker.net/columns/heffner/intro-to-assembly-and-reverse-engineering

```
mov 0xffffffb4,0x1
```

> moves the number 1 into 0xffffffb4.

The problem is, when I tried it with the following C code,

```
int a = 1;
int b = 13;
int c = 133;
```

The assembly language equivalent to that code is like this. (I've got this from GDB)

```
   0x00000000004004ee <+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
   0x00000000004004f5 <+15>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0xd
   0x00000000004004fc <+22>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x85
```

Note that my assembly code moves the number 1 into register RBP.

However, according to the note from that URL, it moves the number 1 into 0xffffffb4 and 0xffffffb4 looks like memory address.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to moves number 1 to memory address instead of register as mentioned in the note?

I've also tested this on Immunity Debugger and found that the value of the variable is moved to the register ESP.

2. Why GDB moves the value to Base Pointer (RBP) while Immunity Debugger moves it to Stack Pointer (ESP)?

[Click here for Immunity Debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFXuJ.jpg)

Comment: I'm no assembly expert, but I'm pretty sure that the square brackets indicate memory dereference, as in `mov [rbp], 0x1` moves the value `1` to the *memory* location *referenced* by the address contained in `rbp`. In this case, I think the compilers vary which register they are using to store the base location of the stack frame, and are storing the variables in memory locations relative to that.

Comment: In this case, locals are allocated on the stack and they are addressed relative to the frame or the stack pointer. The instructions do not move into `rbp` or `rsp`, they move into memory addressed relative to those registers. To get a constant address, use a global or a static variable.

Comment: Then again, in 64 bit mode those in turn may produce rip-relative addressing :)

Comment: `mov 0xffffffb4,0x1` is actually very unfortunate example, as I'm not aware of any Assembler with such syntax. You always have some syntax sugar to distinguish between memory address and immediate value, so better examples would be `mov 0xffffffb4,$0x1` (the `$` marking 1 as value, not address), or `mov [0xffffffb4],0x1` or also `#`/`()` is used in some assemblers. Or with some CPUs there are dedicated instructions of "store/load" kind, where it is clear which argument is memory address and which is value. (on x86 the `mov` is used for almost all combinations)